# Is there a way to make a smoothed kernel density graph when the underlying pdf is known imperfectly?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

First, let me describe my problem.

I have data on the pdf of school attendance by age group. However, ages 3-5 are bundled together in the source. I divided the 3-5 age group by 3 to get the average percentage for each year. However, I now want to estimate what the smoothed shape of the probability density function would be.

Visually, it looks like this:

[image: Bar graph of probability density function with flattened portion]

Now, it makes sense to think, given the rest of the distribution, that more kids are attending at age 5 than at age 3. To estimate this smoothed distribution, I was planning on using seaborn and matplotlib to do kernel density estimation with a higher bandwidth.

These all require a 1-dimensional array of data, whereas my data is 2-dimensional:

```
age = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
density = [5.6, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 13.6, 12.1, 9.6, 7.6, 6.4, 5.4, 4.6, 2.8, 1.4, 1]
```

So is there a way to either (a) do kde with 2-d data or (b) convert 2-d data into 1-d density data?

Answer (score 0):

For 1D kde you can do:

```
pd.Series(density).plot.kde(ind=age)
```

which gives:

[image]